# List Fragment with ActionBarActivity

Tags: java, android, android-listfragment, android-actionbaractivity

If I need to use a toolbar in my Activity but I don't know how to use at the same time an `ActionBarActivity` and a `ListFragment`. What I must to do to mix these two things (`ActionBarActivity` and `ListFragment`?

Comment: What is the problem, exactly? ActionBarActivity extends FragmentActivity, so you'd use the ListFragment just like any other Fragment.

Comment: Thanks @MikeM. I didn´t know it. Where I can find an example?

Comment: I don't know of any specifically, but there's probably relevant examples in the [Android Developer Samples](http://developer.android.com/samples/index.html).